# How to interate over an output list from fetchone() in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, mysql-python

I am currently creating a main menu that acts like a bank account.

```
def main_menu():
    print("Main Menu")
    print("0 - Quit")
    print("1 - Open Account")
    print("2 - Check Balance")
    print("3 - Close Account")


loop = True
while loop:
    main_menu()
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    choice = int(choice)
    if choice == 0:
        exit(loop)
    elif choice == 1:
        name_on_account = input("Name on account: ")
        balance = float(input("Enter Initial Balance: "))
        print("---Account successfully created---")
        print("Account number:", account_no())
        print("Name on account:", name_on_account)
        print("Balance:", balance)
        print("Account opened on:", now)
        cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO account(name_on_account, balance) VALUES 
        ("%s", "%s");""", (name_on_account, balance))
        connection.commit()
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Checking account balance")
        account_number = input("Enter account number: ")
        print("---Checking account balance---")
        print("Account number:", account_number)
        cur.execute("""SELECT * from account;
        """)
        account_no1 = cur.fetchone()
        for i in account_no1[0]:
            if account_number == i:
                cur.execute("""select name_on_account from account where account_no = "%s";
                        """, (account_number,))
                name1 = cur.fetchone()
                print(name1)
                name2 = ''.join(map(str,name1))
                name3 = int(name2)
                print("Name on account:", name3)
                cur.execute("""select balance from account where account_no = "%s";
                        """, account_number)
                balance1 = cur.fetchone()
                balance2 = ''.join(map(str,balance1))
                balance3 = int(balance2)
                print("Balance:", balance3)
                cur.expecute("""select account_open_date from account where account no = "%s";
                        """, account_number)
                date1 = cur.fetchone()
                date2 = ''.join(map(str, date1))
                date3 = int(date2)
                print("Account opened on:", date3)
                connection.commit()
            else:
                print("Error: Invalid account number")
```

I'm not worried about option 3 as of right now, but I am having trouble with option 2.

When a person pick option 1, they will input their name and the amount of money deposited in their bank account.

This information will be stored in the mysql table account(account_no, name_on_account, balance, account_open_date, account_status).

This means that account_no is auto-incremented, account_open_date is default as curdate(), and account_status is default to be "open").

In option 2 however, when a person input their account number; it should return back all of their information how it is displayed in the option 1.

What I am having trouble with is, how do you efficiently iterate over the person's information using fetchone() and be able to get the specific column information with (account_no = account_number) (if you do have a better suggestion on a better way to implement this, please comment below)

This is the error message that I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "(deleted for privacy purposes)"
for i in account_no1[0]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Your "deleted for privacy purposes" removed too much. What line raised the error and where is that line in the code you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pymysql (and most other python mysql clients) is returning a tuple when you invoke `fetchone()`, and each entry in the tuple matches up to the datatypes defined in the table that you're querying. So let's look at your code:

```
elif choice == 2:
    print("Checking account balance")
    account_number = input("Enter account number: ")
    print("---Checking account balance---")
    print("Account number:", account_number)
    cur.execute("""SELECT * from account""")
    account_no1 = cur.fetchone()
    for i in account_no1[0]:
```

Here you're querying all columns and all rows from the `account` table, reading the first row, and then iterating over whatever is in the first column of that row. But that's *probably* just an id column, which is probably why you're getting the error that you're getting: integers are not iterable. That'd be like writing `for i in 10`, Python doesn't understand what that means

If you want to iterate over all of the returned rows, you can do that like this:

```
    cur.execute("""SELECT * from account;
    """)
    for row i in cur.fetchall():
        # Each iteration "row" is a tuple of values corresponding to the table's columns
```

That's kind of silly though. You'd returning all of the rows from the database and then iterating over them and looking for a specific account number. Why not just do that as part of your query?

```
    nrows = cur.execute("SELECT * from account where account_no=%s", (account_number,))
    if nrows == 0:
        # Account number not found, do something
    else:
        row = curs.fetchone()
        # row now contains all of the values from the discovered
```

Note that you don't need to put quotation marks around `%s` placeholders, and you don't need semicolons. The client does all of this conversion for you.

Also note that you should not select `*` from tables. What if the table definition changes to include more columns? Just select the handful of columns that you actually need, then if more columns are added to the table later your code won't need to be changed at all and you won't be requesting more data than you need. So more like:

```
nrows = cur.execute("SELECT name, balance, date_opened from account where account_no=%s", (account_number,))
if nrows > 0:
    name, balance, date_opened = curs.fetchone()
```